# Set terminal title to current file name and path with Vim

Tags: vim, terminal, ansi-escape

I would like Vim to send the name of the currently open file to macOS Terminal.

It is possible to tell the macOS terminal the filename of a currently open document by sending the escape sequence `\e]6;FILENAME\a`. This can be seen be executing the command `printf "\e]6;FileName.txt\a"`

I would like Vim to send the filename of the currently open document to Terminal. It seems like this should be easy, but `:echo "\e]6;FileName.txt\007"` will turn the escape sequences into printable characters and add some color to them, so it instead outputs `^[]6;FileName.txt^G` which is not recognized by Terminal.

How can I configure `:echo` not to mangle my escape sequences?

Comment: See `:help 'title'`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to send escape sequences from within Vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32429471/how-to-send-escape-sequences-from-within-vim)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Thank you @romainl; this was as simple as adding `set title` to my `~/.vimrc` file.

Comment: you saved my day! I was using before workaround to run vim like `vim /path/to/file` in order to have terminal tab using correct title..

Answer (score 0):

```
set title
```

to the ~/.vimrc file does put the file being edited
onto the terminal heading, very useful if several tabs are open.

You can also add

```
oldtitle=
```

which will retore the terminals original title.
Otherwise VIM wites a "thanks for flying VIM" message on
exit.